# How to set the height and width of multiple iframes by form input using jquery?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I am trying to set the height and width of multiple iframes by the **H** and **W** text fields on form. I am only able to set the height and width of the first iframe, if I try to set the height and width of a second, third, and so on, the height and width that was entered for those particular iframes are declared as undefined. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var max_fields = 10;
  var wrapper = $("#dbForm");
  var add_another = $("#add_another");
  var x = 1;

  $(add_another).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) {
      x++;
      $(wrapper).append('<div class="form-group file_group">' +
        '<label for="filename">Filename:</label>' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control filename" style="margin:4px;">' +
        '<label for="height" style="margin-right:4px;">H:</label>' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control height" name="height" style="margin-right:4px;">' +
        '<label for="width" style="margin-right:4px;">W:</label>' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control width" name="width" style="margin-right:4px;">' +
        '<button class="btn btn-danger btnRemoveModule"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>Remove</button></div>');
    }
    if (x == 1) {$('.btnAddModule').html('Add Module');} 
    else if (x > 1) {$('.btnAddModule').html('Add Modules');}
  });

  $('.btnAddModule').click(function(e) {
    $('.filename').each(function(i) {
      if ($(this).val() == "") {e.stopPropagation();} 
      else {
        $('<iframe scrolling="yes" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="1" vspace="0" hspace="0">')
          .attr('src', $(this).val())


           // I am setting the height and width here
          .attr('width', $('.width').val() + '%') 
          .attr('height', $('.height').val() + 'px')


          .appendTo('#dashboard');

        $('<input type="hidden" id="position_' + i + '" name="position" value="' + i + '">').appendTo('#dbForm');
        $('#main_file, #main_width, #main_height').val("");
        $('.file_group:not(first-child)').remove();
        $('.container').hide();
        $('#control_panel').css("display", "block");
      }
    });
    $('iframe').draggable({iframeFix: true});
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".btnRemoveModule", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
    if (x == 1) {$('.btnAddModule').html('Add Module');} 
    else if (x > 1) {$('.btnAddModule').html('Add Modules');}
  });

  $('#close_add_rpt').click(function() {
    $('.container').hide();
    $('#control_panel').css("display", "block");
  });

  $('#control_panel').click(function() {
    $('.container').show();
    $('#control_panel').css("display", "none");
  });

});
```

```css
iframe {
  resize: both;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input:active,
input:focus,
button:focus,
button:active {
  outline: none!important;
  -webkit-appearance: none!important;
}

.filename,
.height,
.width {
  width: 700px!important;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important
}

.filename:active,
.filename:focus,
.height:active,
.height:focus,
.width:active,
.width:focus {
  outline: none!important;
  -webkit-appearance: none!important;
}

.height,
.width {
  width: 55px!important;
}

#control_panel {
  margin: 0px auto 20px auto;
  display: block;
  display: none;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.container #close_wrap {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}

.container #close_wrap .glyphicon-remove {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #d9534f;
}

.container #close_wrap .glyphicon-remove:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#main_form_group {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

#dbForm {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#button_wrap {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.btnAddModule {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#add_another {
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.file_group {
  display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<button id="control_panel" class="btn btn-primary">Control Panel</button>

<div class="container">
  <div id="close_wrap"><span id="close_add_rpt" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></div>
  <h2>Add Modules to Dashboard</h2>
  <form id="dbForm" class="form-inline" onsubmit="return false">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">
    <div id="main_form_group" class="form-group">
      <label for="filename">Filename:</label>
      <input id="main_file" type="text" class="form-control filename" name="filename">
      <label for="height">H:</label>
      <input id="main_height" type="text" class="form-control height" name="height">
      <label for="width">W:</label>
      <input id="main_width" type="text" class="form-control width" name="width">
    </div>
  </form>
  <div id="button_wrap">
    <button id="add_another" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add Another</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btnAddModule">Add Module</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dashboard"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that if I understand what this should do but I didn't get the error. For me it's works fine your code snippet.

Comment: @RobertNegreanu Try setting the width and height for two filenames. The first iframe will display the exact width and height that you entered, but the second will not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you think about this modification? Maybe you want some information for user that one field is px and another %

```
$('.form-group').each(function(i) { //here
  if ($(".filename",this).val() == "") {e.stopPropagation();} //here
  else {
    $('<iframe scrolling="yes" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="1" vspace="0" hspace="0">')
      .attr('src', $(".filename",this).val()) //here


       // I am setting the height and width here
      .attr('width', $('.width',this).val() + '%') //here
      .attr('height', $('.height',this).val() + 'px') //here
      .appendTo('#dashboard');

    $('<input type="hidden" id="position_' + i + '" name="position" value="' + i + '">').appendTo('#dbForm');
    $('#main_file, #main_width, #main_height').val("");
    $('.file_group:not(first-child)').remove();
    $('.container').hide();
    $('#control_panel').css("display", "block");
  }
});
```

Comment: Holy smokes thanks a million man! That's exactly what I was looking for.